# Copy RTF to clipboard - How to specify Font type?

Tags: notepad++, export-to-word

I know that Notepad++  has this awesome NPP Export plugin that allows to easily copy formated text to the clipboard to insert it e.g. into PowerPoint, and I am already using it.

However, although the text is always inserted with color and all it keeps using the Arial font, event though I already changed the default font in the "Settings"->"Style Configurator..." to "Courier New"

Therefore my questions:

1. Where can I find the Settings for NPPExport?
2. Where can I specify which font NPPExport uses when it copies the text to the clipboard?

Regards Markus

p.s. 
I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, but I just keep finding articles that tell me that I can copy the text (Which I already know) but not what I am looking for...

Comment: Are you using `enable global font` ? I've just tried this and seems to be working for me

Comment: It seems as this is a problem with PowerPoint 2013 but not with Word... damn...

Comment: I think you could have more luck with this question over at https://superuser.com